# Solving a maze in 2d array

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I had referred to many articles and questions that answered how to solve a maze effectively but here I want to confirm what's going wrong in my code. Consider the maze:

```
2 1 0 0 3
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

where the 1's represent the walls and 0's represent the path.(source is 2 and destination is 3).
I have to output whether there is a path or not.

```
int y=0;
        while(y==0)
        {
            robo1(n,m,maze);//this function adds 2 to any '0'/'3' in (i,j+1),(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j-1) (if exists),where (i,j) is 2
            robo2(n,m,k2,maze);//this function adds 3 to any '0'/'2' in (i,j+1),(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j-1) (if exists), where (i,j) is 3
            if(find5(n,m,maze)==1)//this function returns 1 if there is '5' in the maze
                y++;
            if(find0(n,m,maze)==0)//this function returns 0 if there are no '0' in the maze
                break;
        }
        if(find0(n,m,maze)==0 && y==0)
            printf("-1\n");//no path
        else
            printf("1\n");//there is a path
```

My idea is that if after any number of loops a five is found in the maze, then it would mean there is a path. 
But while implementing this function in code I get wrong answers and sometimes run-time errors.
Is there any flaw in the above logic?

Comment: Please provide implementation of `robo1`, `robo2`, `find5`, `find0`. Runtime errors mean that you possibly go out of bounds in any of these functions, but without the code it's hard to tell

Comment: To me it's not clear what the approach is. Are you aware of [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)?

Comment: The problem is most probably in `robo*` and `find*`, so please post it as @buld0zzr said.  The logic here I think it's alright (though it's not the "best" ) as it is basically a brute force bi-direction BFS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea should almost work, but of course everything is in the details.

One case in which your approach will not work even if implemented correctly is however this:

```
  2 1 0 0 0
  1 1 0 1 1 
  0 0 0 1 3
```

i.e. if both 2 and 3 are "closed" by walls but there are 0s in the room. Your loop will never end because despite having 0s around neither of the two robo function will change anything.

A simple solution is returning 0/1 from robos if they actually changed at least a value in the matrix and quitting when this doesn't happen.

Note that this is not a very efficient way of solving a maze (your code will keep checking the same cells over and over many times).

Comment: Good example to show the algorithm itself (implementation I suppose) is not working!

Comment: Thanks.....I had gone through some approaches like DFS and A* which are much effective than the above approach.....just wanted to know the defects in this approach